# Spyder not showing stderr output in IPython console when running commands with os.system

Tags: ipython, spyder, stderr

Setup: MacOS High Sierra, Spyder 3.3.1, Python 2.7.15 64bits, Qt 5.9.4, PyQt5 5.9.2 on Darwin

I run the following code in the IPython console within Spyder:

```
In [1]: import os
In [2]: os.system("ls")
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: os.system("aasdasd") 
Out[3]: 32512
```

I can see the output to stdout of the `ls` command in the bash shell where I run spyder, but not to stderr of the second `os.system` call that should print `sh: asdasd: command not found`.

Where does spyder redirect stderr to? Is there a way to see error messages like the one generated in the second case?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This was fixed in `spyder-kernels` **0.3.0**, the package that provides kernels for our consoles. And by fixed I mean that both stdout and stderr of external commands are now shown directly in our IPython consoles.

To update `spyder-kernels`, please close Spyder and run in a system terminal (xterm or Terminal.app, this doesn't work on Windows):

`conda install spyder-kernels=0.*`

if you use Anaconda (it's not available at the moment, but it should be shortly, please wait until it is), or

`pip install spyder-kernels==0.*`

if you use a custom Python installation.

Comment: Then please mark my answer as correct by pressing the green check mark below the counter on the left. Thanks!